# On the elliptic curve $X^3+6d^2X-7d^3 = Y^2$ and the ellipse $p^2+3q^2-d = 0$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, elliptic-curves, conic-sections

From the ellipse $p^2+3q^2 - d = 0$ we can find a solution to the equation,

$$a^3+b^3+c^3 = (c+m)^3$$

if we solve the elliptic curve,

$$E:=X^3+6d^2X-7d^3 = Y^2$$

More details can be found in [this MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4847666/on-the-elliptic-curve-x3-6-cdot-1632-x-7-cdot-1633-y2-and-others). The useful $d$ would be those such that $E$ has positive rank. For simplicity, we focus on prime $d$. Primes of form $d=x^2+3y^2=1\,(\text{mod}\,6)$ can easily be divided into two kinds: $d = x^2+72y^2$ and $d \neq x^2+72y^2$. My two observations are:

- If $d = x^2+72y^2$, then $E$ has even rank.
- If $d \neq x^2+72y^2$, then $E$ has odd rank.

For the former, most have rank $r=0$ with the smallest being $d=73$, but some have rank $r=2$ such has $d=313$. For the latter, most (or all?) have rank $r=1$ with the smallest being $d=7,13,19,$ though I haven't found one yet with rank $r=3$.

---

**Question 1**: Are the two observations in fact true for all $d$? (The partial answer in the other post seems to verify the observation for $d<40000$.)

**Question 2**: Is it true that a necessary (but not sufficient) condition for $E$  to have rank $r=2$ is that $d = x^2+144y^2$? (All known with $r=2$ have that form.)

Comment: $E$ is the $d$-th quadratic twist of (the rank-$0$ elliptic curve) $X^3+6X-7=Y^2$, so the rank is the same as the one of the latter curve over the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$. The parity of the latter rank would be expected by BSD to be an explicitly given product of local root numbers, so (without having checked how the computation boils down in this case) the two observations should probably at least be verifiable conditionally on BSD.

Comment: @JoachimKönig Great! Is the rank of $E$ only $r = 0,1,2$, or is $r=3,4$ possible as well? (I tried searching for $r=4$ amongst $d=x^2+144y^2<25000$ but no luck.)

Comment: Numerically, for $(d,6)=1$, it looks like the root number of the twist $E_d$ is equal to the root number at $2$ as $w_3=w_{\infty}=-1$ and $w_p=+1$ for $p\mid d$. It seems $w_2=-1$ if and only if $d\equiv 5 \pmod{8}$, but I haven't check this very far. Conjecturally on the finiteness of the Tate-Shafarevich group, we know the partiy conjecture, which would then give you a condition on the rank being even or odd only on $d$ modulo 8. --- But maybe I am completely wrong. It shouldn't be hard to do this explicitly as Joachim suggested already.

Comment: This does not say anything about the rank itself. We expect as usual that 0 and 1 are the most frequent for each of the two root numbers. But I see no reason to think there aren't any with much larger rank.

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich Ok, perhaps it is just $0, 1, 2$ then. I do find it curious that that 22 $d$ that I have found so far such that $E$ has rank $2$ are of form $d=x^2+144y^2$, no exceptions. I’ll check more. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Oh, silly me, of course the rank is bounded. There is a 2-isogeny to the curve $y^2 = (x+5d)(x+2d)(x-7d)$. If $d$ is prime then only 2,3 and $d$ are bad, so from complete 2-descent, only taking the infinite local conditions, we know that the rank has to be at most 3. Probably one can get that down to 2 by looking at 2-adic local conditions. And a precise formula for the rank of the 2-Selmer group could be found and would depend on $d$ modulo some power of 2 and 3. But I won't have time to do this myself. Having to mark lots of 2-descents doen by my student in their exam.

Comment: Correction, it is at most 4. - But I should really stop thinking about this...